# Use system() to create independent child process

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, fork, system-calls

I have written a program where I create a thread in the main and use `system()` to start another process from the thread. Also I start the same process using the `system()` in the main function also. The process started from the thread seems to stay alive even when the parent process dies. But the one called from the main function dies with the parent. Any ideas why this is happening.

Please find the code structure below:

```
void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
     system(command.c_str());        
}

int main()
{
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
    .... 
    system(command.c_str());
    while (true)
    {
        ....
    }
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your definition for `thread_func()` is not correct - it lacks an argument. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads#Example) which shows an example.

Comment: @kiner_shah This is just a skeleton. I do have the thing in my actual code

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is: Don't do what you do. If you want to create an independently running child-process, research the [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`exec` family](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions. Which is what `system` will use "under the hood".

Threads aren't really independent the same way processes are. When your "main" process ends, all threads end as well. In your specific case the thread seems to continue to run while the main process seems to end because of the `pthread_join` call, it will simply wait for the thread to exit. If you remove the join call the thread (and your "command") will be terminated.

There are ways to *detach* threads so they can run a little more independently (for example you don't have to join a detached thread) but the main process still can't end, instead you have to end the main *thread*, which will keep the process running for as long as there are detached threads running.

---

Using `fork` and `exec` is actually quite simple, and not very complex:

```
int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    // We are in the child process, execute the command
    execl(command.c_str(), command.c_str(), nullptr);

    // If execl returns, there was an error
    std::cout << "Exec error: " << errno << ", " << strerror(errno) << '\n';

    // Exit child process
    exit(1);
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
    // The parent process, do whatever is needed
    // The parent process can even exit while the child process is running, since it's independent
}
else
{
    // Error forking, still in parent process (there are no child process at this point)
    std::cout << "Fork error: " << errno << ", " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
}
```

The exact variant of `exec` to use depends on `command`. If it's a valid path (absolute or relative) to an executable program then `execl` works well. If it's a "command" in the `PATH` then use `execlp`.

Comment: I concur with answer. Additionally, if all you need is to capture output of a command, and you don't need it to run after main process dies, this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix

Comment: @ErikAlapää Good link. But the accepted answer do have a flaw with the `while (!feof(...))` loop (as pointed out in the comments).

Comment: Don't I need a double fork, as I want the parent process to continue and not wait for the child process.

Comment: @YashKapoor Unless you want to get the exit-status of the child process, you never need to wait for it. If the child-process becomes orphaned, the "init" process will take over as parent and reap it when the child-process ends.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried the above code sample you posted. So, whenever I kill the parent process with Ctrl+C, the child process also dies

Comment: I added the following condition under (pid==0) and the child becomes independent.

    **if (setsid() < 0)
    return false;**

Comment: @YashKapoor It has to do with *process groups*.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points here that I think you've missed:

First, `system` is a synchronous call. That means, your program (or, at least, the thread calling `system`) *waits* for the child to complete. So, if your `command` is long-running, both your main thread and your worker thread will be blocked until it completes.

Secondly, you are "joining" the worker thread at the end of `main`. This is the right thing to do, because unless you join or detach the thread you have undefined behaviour. However, it's not what you really intended to do. The end result is not that the child process continues after your main process ends... your main process is still alive! It is blocked on the `pthread_join` call, which is trying to wrap up the worker thread, which is still running `command`.

In general, assuming you wish to spawn a new process entirely unrelated to your main process, threads are not the way to do it. Even if you were to detach your thread, it still belongs to your process, and you are still required to let it finish before your process terminates. You can't detach from the process using threads.

Instead, you'll need OS features such as `fork` and `exec` (or a friendly C++ wrapper around this functionality, such as Boost.Subprocess). This is the only way to truly spawn a new process from within your program.

But, you can cheat! If `command` is a shell command, and your shell supports background jobs, you could put `&` at the end of the command (this is an example for Bash syntax) to make the `system` call:

- Ask the shell to spin off a new process
- Wait for it to do that
- The new process will now continue to run in the background

For example:

```
const std::string command = "./myLongProgram &";
//                                           ^
```

However, again, this is kind of a hack and proper fork mechanisms that reside *within* your program's logic should be preferred for maximum portability and predictability.